# MS SQL stored procedure to insert or update total YTD & Previous year invoice totals

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to total both current financial YTD invoiced sales & previous financial year invoiced sales on a daily basis for each customer in a MS SQL database and populate a separate table with this information. This information will be available within an application with specific functionality.

There are 3 x tables that contain pertinent information:

- Customers (list of all customers in system)
- Invoice (all invoice data)
- CustomData (custom fields that can be created and populated in an application that interacts with the database)

I am looking for advice on how best to implement a solution that achieves the following:

- Checks the current date to see if it is the 1st day of financial year (1st April)
- If it is, loop through every record in the customer table that satisfies an argument (live customer) and total the net value - value of credit notes of both the invoices raised in the previous financial year (1st April - 31st March) and current financial YTD (from the 1st April) where the customer ID in the invoice table matches the ID in the customer table.

  Then check the CustomData table to see if records for that customerID exist > if they do, update the record with new value (NB null values should = 0), if it doesn't exist, insert the data into the CustomData table.
- If the current date is not 1st April, then only total the current financial YTD sales and update/insert into CustomData as required

The tables are constructed as follows (columns that are not relevant to this process have been excluded):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [CustomerStatus] [tinyint] NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT [DF_Customers_CustomerStatus]  DEFAULT ((0)),

    CONSTRAINT [PK__Customers] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Invoice]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Datedb] [datetime] NULL,
    [AccountNo] [varchar](32) NULL,
    [Nett] [float] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_InvoiceHead_Nett]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [IsCreditNote] [tinyint] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_InvoiceHead_IsCreditNote]  DEFAULT ((0)),

     CONSTRAINT [PK__InvoiceHead] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomData]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomFieldsContentID] [int] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_CustomFieldsData_CustomFieldsContentID]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [ModuleID] [int] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_CustomFieldsData_ModuleID]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [ModuleType] [tinyint] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_CustomFieldsData_ModuleType]  DEFAULT ((0)),
    [ValueNumber] [float] NULL,
    [dbTimeStamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK__CustomFieldsData] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The customer relationship is Customers.Code Invoice.AccountNo & CustomData.ModuleID

Customers are live if Customers.CustomerStatus = 2

The CustomData.CustomFieldsContentID = 32 for previous financial year invoiced sales and 33 for YTD invoiced sales.

CustomData.ModuleID is the customer code (Customers.Code & Invoice.AccountNo)

CustomData.ModuleType will be a static value = 18

CustomData.ValueNumber will be the sum of the nett invoice value.

Invoice.IsCreditNote = 1 requires the nett value of that record to be a negative figure.

I'm not familiar with using cursors to loop through the records and also not sure the most efficient way to do this! I don't really know where to start!

Comment: Loop through the table?  Why not a simple query that includes `sum(something)`?

Comment: Where to start?  Start with something very simple and do one thing at a time.  I suggest with figuring out how to determine whether or not it's April 1st.

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: If this is for **SQL Server**, I would ***strongly*** advise against using `FLOAT` as a datatype. It's inherently imprecise, and not a good match for when you're dealing with money values. Use `DECIMAL(p,s)` instead

Comment: Which DBMS?  SQL is just a language.  It doesn't tell which dbms you are using.

Comment: DBMS is MS SQL server. With regards to the float datatype, we are not able to influence this as this is software supplied by a vendor.